# What is the ID and status option in the data payload of a firebase cloud message for Flutter when using FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does anyone know if I need to manage the data `id` and `status` options in the flutter firebase messaging example?

I can't seem to find this mentioned at https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging or https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload

The `curl` example in the Flutter docs is like so:

```
DATA='{"notification": {"body": "this is a body","title": "this is a title"}, "priority": "high", "data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "id": "1", "status": "done"}, "to": "<FCM TOKEN>"}'
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "$DATA" -H "Authorization: key=<FCM SERVER KEY>"
```

I'm trying to figure out if I need to manage the `id` and `status` values in my backend service. Looks like it, but what are others doing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data field is just an arbitrary key value payload, `id` and `status` were just examples, See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Message.FIELDS.data

Please note that the curl example provided is using the legacy HTTP protocol.

firebase_messaging passes an event to flutter when `data.click_action` or `notification.click_action` is `"FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"`, See:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/4f0c5dd2bd30673446a8d511f7a791af9757eb3e/packages/firebase_messaging/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.java#L179-L208

Comment: Thanks! what is the preferred curl way now?